# C++ binary search with char array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

so I have structure for competitors. I use binary search to search competitors by their surnames. This is the code:

```
int binary(tekmovalec abc[], int n, char x[20])
{
 int start = 0;
 int end = n-1;

 int a= strlen(x);

 while(start <=end)
 {

     int mid = (start+end)/2;

     if(abc[mid].surName[0]== x[0])
     { 

     print(tekmovalci[mid]);
     return mid;

     }


     else if(x[0]<abc[mid].surName[0])
     {
         end = mid -1;


     }
     else
     {start = mid +1;}

 }

return -1;

 }
```

I have a problem, that function checks only first letter of surname and input array, so if surname is Obrien, and user input is "Obrb" it prints Obrien. I dont know how to expand function to check for all letters of user input. Thank you.

Comment: [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)?

Comment: `std::string`, to complete the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strcmp` to compare the strings in the loop.

```
int res = strcmp(x, abc[mid].surName);
if(!res)
 { 

 print(tekmovalci[mid]);
 return mid;

 }


 else if(res < 0)
 {
     end = mid -1;


 }
 else
 {start = mid +1;}
```